# Endless Errors when trying to set cors on azure storage account / Blob

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to set up cors on an azure storage blob account, that I have added a CDN to.
the reason is so that I can serve the web fonts from there and get the caching.

I have installed latest software from nuget:

Successfully added 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.0' to Impulse.
Adding 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 1.8.0.0' to Impulse.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 1.8.0.0' to Impulse.
Adding 'WindowsAzure.Storage 4.2.1' to Impulse.
Successfully added 'WindowsAzure.Storage 4.2.1' to Impulse.

I have then used this C# code :

```
private void AzureCors()
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("removed","removed"), true);
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            ServiceProperties blobServiceProperties = new ServiceProperties();
            blobServiceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(new CorsRule(){
                AllowedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
                AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Put | CorsHttpMethods.Get | CorsHttpMethods.Head | CorsHttpMethods.Post,
                AllowedOrigins = new List<string>() { "*" },
                ExposedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
                MaxAgeInSeconds = 3600 // 30 minutes 
            });

            blobClient.SetServiceProperties(blobServiceProperties);
        }
```

This first error is The logging version is null or empty.    however this according to MS is no longer required, but I added it anyway.   Then I get an error that the Metrics Version is null or empty, however this too is not supposed to be required, but not only that, but is actually discontinued from 4.2.1 and I am unable to set metrics anyway, and the code to now use is HourMetrics, however, filling in an hour metrics still gives an error for metrics.

So what is going on, how the hell am I supposed to connect to azure storage, if none off the libraries actually work?

### as a sidenote   I have installed the latest azure SDK into visual studio 2013 Yesterday

not sure if this could be an issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    private void AzureCors()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("removed", "removed"), true);
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        ServiceProperties blobServiceProperties = new ServiceProperties()
        {
            HourMetrics = null,
            MinuteMetrics = null,
            Logging = null,
        };
        blobServiceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(new CorsRule()
        {
            AllowedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
            AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Put | CorsHttpMethods.Get | CorsHttpMethods.Head | CorsHttpMethods.Post,
            AllowedOrigins = new List<string>() { "*" },
            ExposedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
            MaxAgeInSeconds = 3600 // 30 minutes 
        });

        blobClient.SetServiceProperties(blobServiceProperties);
    }
```

Basically when you create an instance of `ServiceProperties`, all properties like `HourMetrics` etc. get initialized. What you need to do is forcefully set the properties you don't want to change to `null` and this is what I did in the constructor.

Comment: very good, thanks, worked like a charm and also solved my issue with cors all in one :-)

Comment: One thing you may want to keep in mind is that the code above will overwrite existing CORS rules. If you want to add a new CORS rule to existing CORS rules, you would need to do `GetServiceProperties` first. HTH.

Comment: noted but I have literally just set this up today as fresh so was just a matter of initial config to get fonts working