# Azure Blob Architecture/Usage Scenario: Dynamic Blog Containers and Uploading/Viewing Images

Tags: javascript, azure

I am working on a Web project where users will need a dedicated "workspace" for uploading and viewing image that are specific to them. My current thinking is that I would leverage Azure Blob Storage where:

1) On click (perhaps after filling out a form) users would get their own blob container where they can upload and view files they have uploaded

2) Users would not be able to view others' blob containers (SAS)

3) Users could login later and "pick up where they left off" by referencing Blob containers tied to their username (I envision using Azure Mobile Services to store references to usernames and the blobs they have)

I have a hard requirement to achieve this via JavaScript (I am using an AngularJS application) and would include node.js as a option.

My questions are as follows:

1) Is Azure Blob Storage the right solution for a scenario such as this?

2) How would I programmatically create containers via JavaScript?

3) What is the preferred method for using JavaScript (jQuery, etc.) to upload files? I have already enabled CORS and set a sample blob to Public for testing but am still getting a Cross Origin error with a PUT request. Do I need SAS with a public blob?

4) Is there anything beyond a PUT that I would need to overwrite an existing image?

5) MOST Importantly: Are their alternative architectures or solutions the community would recommended given that users expect to view their uploaded images in short order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is Azure Blob Storage the right solution for a scenario such as
>   this?

For storing images in Azure, Blob Storage is the best place.

> 2) How would I programmatically create containers via JavaScript?

Technically you could create containers via JavaScript using REST API but it is not recommended as only account owners can create containers right now (or in other words, one would need account key to create a container). What you could do is when a user registers at that time create a container in your server-side script.

> 3) What is the preferred method for using JavaScript (jQuery, etc.) to
>   upload files? I have already enabled CORS and set a sample blob to
>   Public for testing but am still getting a Cross Origin error with a
>   PUT request. Do I need SAS with a public blob?

You could use jQuery or Angular (depending on your level of comfort). I wrote a blog post on uploading blobs using jQuery that you can read here: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/12/01/windows-azure-storage-and-cors-lets-have-some-fun/. I'm not able to find it but I remember somebody writing the same in Angular as well.

Regarding CORS error (I saw your other question as well), try setting the allowed origins to `"*"`. For some reason, setting origin to `"localhost:someport"` does not work well.

You don't need SAS to read (download) a public blob. However you would need SAS to perform operations like upload and changing blob properties etc.

> 4) Is there anything beyond a PUT that I would need to overwrite an
>   existing image?

I don't think so. I would recommend reading up on blob storage REST API so that you're passing proper headers in your request.

> 5) MOST Importantly: Are their alternative architectures or solutions
>   the community would recommended given that users expect to view their
>   uploaded images in short order

Personally, this architecture looks fine to me. In fact, I use it heavily in my application. But I would be interested in hearing thoughts from other folks as well.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I will need to look at getting SAS working for the upload and appreciate the review. I tried setting the origin to a wildcard via Azure Storage Explorer, but it stated that "An Allowed Origin must be a value URI"

Comment: Yes, Azure Storage Explorer has this issue :(. Try the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826216/endless-errors-when-trying-to-set-cors-on-azure-storage-account-blob/25826407. HTH.

Comment: Per server side container creation, would Node.js as documented here be an option? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage/

Comment: Absolutely. You can use Node.js Azure Storage SDK to create blob containers for your users.

Comment: With Node.js it looks like there is an upload function, so in either case it looks like Node will be the first stop given the requirements for creating custom blob containers.

Comment: If you use Node to upload the blobs, then the content will always go through your servers. With SAS uploads, users will be directly uploading the content in your storage account without being routed through your servers. This will improve the overall performance of your application IMHO.